# How to mock an array of interfaces using powermock or mockito

Tags: mockito, powermock, powermockito

I am mocking an interface array which throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class.`

Following are the changes I did.

Added the following annotations at class level in this exact order:

```java
@Runwith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ Array1[].class, Array2[].class })
```

Inside the class I am doing like this:

```java
Array1[] test1= PowerMockito.mock(Array1[].class);
Array2[] test2= PowerMockito.mock(Array2[].class);
```

and inside test method:

```java
Mockito.when(staticclass.somemethod()).thenReturn(test1);
Mockito.when(staticclass.somediffmethod()).thenReturn(test2);
```

Basically I need to mock an array of interfaces.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Opening up another perspective on your problem: I think you are getting unit tests wrong.

You only use mocking frameworks in order to **control** the **behavior** of **individual** objects that you provide to your code under test. But there is no sense in **mocking** an array of something.

When your "class under test" needs to deal with some array, list, map, whatever, then you provide an array, a list, or a map to it - you just make sure that the elements within that array/collection ... are as you need them. Maybe the array is empty for one test, maybe it contains a null for another test, and maybe it contains a mocked object for a third test.

Meaning - you don't do:

```
SomeInterface[] test1 = PowerMock.mock() ...
```

Instead you do:

```
SomeInterface[] test1 = new SomeInterface[] { PowerMock.mock(SomeInterface.class) };
```

And allow for some notes:

- At least in your code, it looks like you called your interface "Array1" and "Array2". That is highly misleading. Give interfaces names that say what their behavior is about. The fact that you later create arrays containing objects of that interface ... doesn't matter at all!
- Unless you have good reasons - consider **not** using PowerMock. PowerMock relies on byte-code manipulation; and can simply cause a lot of problems. In most situations, people wrote **untestable** code; and then they turn to PowerMock to somehow test that. But the correct answer is to rework that broken design, and to use a mocking framework that comes without "power" in its name. You can watch those [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79) giving you lengthy explanations how to write testable code!